# jQuery, how to check for a selected option from a form select?

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I have this form select:

```
<select name="select_date" id="select_date">
    <optgroup label="Select Date">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Custom Date</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Or Custom Date">
        <option value="1"> Current Month</option>
        <option value="2"> Last Month</option>
        <option value="3"> Last 3 Months</option>
        <option value="4"> Last 6 Months</option>
        <option value="5"> Last Ever</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<div id="test">hide me</div>
```

How can I check for a selected option so that: `if option 3 selected then hide the div with id test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#test").toggle($("#select_date").val() != 3);
```

Wrapped in an event handler for the `change` event:

```
$("#select_date").bind("change", function () {
    $("#test").toggle(this.value != 3);
}).change();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qde8d/

**Notes:**

- Use the version of [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) that takes a `showOrHide` parameter to show `#test` when the selected option is not 3, and hide it when it is 3.
- Access the current value of the `select` element using `this.value` inside the event handler or [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) if you're working with a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3qyU/2/)

```
$('#select_date').change(function() {
    $('#test').show();
    if($(this).val() === '3') {
        $('#test').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to quote the literal 3. Fixed now :)

Comment: thanks, i chose Andrew Whitaker answer because it worked first, but yours is working as well. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select_date').change(function(){
    if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 3) $('div#test').hide();
});
```

**Edit:** Bonus: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwick/j3qyU/1/)